# Iterating through a date property in a feature collection to get before and after an event images

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have 50 points uploaded into Earth Engine with a date property. Each of the point has a varied date. I would like to iterate through each point selecting the date and use it to get 10day before and after images as shown in lines 55 & 56 of the code.

I have tried writing the function below but it is not working.

```
function swarmdates(date){
  var swarmDate = ee.Date.get('date')
  var beforeDate = swarmDate.advance(-11,'day')
  var afterDate = swarmDate.advance(11,'day')
  return date.set('invasion_date', invasion_date)
}

var swarmdate = invasionbuffer.map(swarmdates)

print(swarmdate)
```

Here's a link to full code; https://code.earthengine.google.com/24d95ba1a2a45cdd15b9ed13e974c1ec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you map a Collection, it is mandatory to return a feature or an image. So, it is easier to convert collections in lists for returning other properties as dates. However, your function has a not declared variable (invasion_date) and it has not sense to return it. So, I modified your function as follows for returning all calculated dates as list (swarmDate, beforeDate, afterDate). If you only are interested in swarmDate you can easily modify this function deleting not desired dates and square brackets.

```
var listOfFeats = invasionbuffer.toList(invasionbuffer.size());

var swarmdate = listOfFeats.map(function (feat){
  var swarmDate = ee.Feature(feat).get('STARTDATE')
  var beforeDate = ee.Date(swarmDate).advance(-11,'day')
  var afterDate = ee.Date(swarmDate).advance(11,'day')
  //return date.set('invasion_date', invasion_date)
  return [swarmDate, beforeDate, afterDate];
});

print("swarmdate", swarmdate);
```

Complete code is in following [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/33692c6daae716d1e210051694c8d971).

In the following image, you can observe (red rectangle) printed dates for first feature of invasionbuffer.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for taking your time for offering such a clear and comprehensive explanation. Much appreciated and well understood. This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I can proceed with my analysis. Thanks a lot.