# Different data ranges from multiple polygons to obtain mean value from Image collection

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, spatio-temporal-data

What I am trying to do is from a shapefile  that contains polygons (> 1000, simplified for this posting) and respective date of the fire ('FIRE_START') to:

1. Calculate new dates to be used as time range of the analysis (between 21 days and 1 day before the fire) for each polygon
2. Use the created dates as time ranges to create multiple ImageCollections (one for each polygon)
3. Then with those multiple ImageCollections, I would be able to obtain the NDVI mean value  for each.

I was trying to apply the solution here presented ([Iterating through a date property in a feature collection to get before and after an event images](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413596/iterating-through-a-date-property-in-a-feature-collection-to-get-before-and-afte?sem=2) ) but I am not obtaining the data I was expecting (one NDVI band for polygon?).

Also I don't understand why they would define a specific date as firestart as in that way I only get images in that interval. But if I don't do it, I can't filter.date the Imagecollection as appears undefined.

Below is my script and basedata.

```js
// // // Set study area as map center.
Map.centerObject(fires);


///////  FIRE START 

// EPOCH to FORMAT YYYY-MM-DD

  // fire start 
function epoch2date_start(feature){
  var epoch = feature.get('FIRE_START');
  var date = ee.Date(epoch).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  //return table.set('FIRE_START', date);
  return feature.set('dateFIRE', date);
}

var firesDate = fires.map(epoch2date_start);

print(firesDate);

//// OBTAIN TIME RANGES FOR THE ANALYSIS

var ListofFires = fires.toList(fires.size()); 
print(ListofFires)

var firestart = ee.Date('2015-08-30');
var prefire_start = firestart.advance(-21,'day');
var prefire_end = firestart.advance(-1,'day');

var prefire_dates = ListofFires.map(function (feat){
  var firestart = ee.Feature(feat).get('FIRE_START')
  var prefire_start = ee.Date(firestart).advance(-21,'day')
  var prefire_end = ee.Date(firestart).advance(-1,'day')
  return [prefire_start, prefire_end]; //colunas a selecionar para a tabela
});

print("prefire_dates", prefire_dates);


// //------------------------------- Apply a cloud and snow mask -------------------------------
//Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).set({'system:index':image.get('system:index'),
                                                   'system:time_start': image.get('system:time_start')});
}

// // //----------------------- Select Landsat imagery by time and location -----------------------


 var prefireImCol = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
        .filter(ee.Filter.date(prefire_start, firestart))
        .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 70))
        .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(fires.geometry()))
        .map(maskS2clouds);   

print('beforeCollection', prefireImCol.sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE'))

var beforeImage = prefireImCol.median().clip(fires.geometry())


var pre_mos = prefireImCol.mosaic().clip(fires);
//var post_mos = postfireImCol.mosaic().clip(area);



  var preNBR = pre_mos.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B12'])



// Add the NBR images to the console on the right
print("Pre-fire Normalized Burn Ratio: ", preNBR); 
  
Map.addLayer(beforeImage, bfndviVis, 'bf_ndvi')





// //----------------------- Mosaic and clip images to study area -----------------------------

// var pre_mos = prefireImCol.mosaic().clip(area);

// var pre_cm_mos = prefire_CM_ImCol.mosaic().clip(area);


// print("Pre-fire True Color Image: ", pre_mos);
```

Script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fllopes%2FESR%3Afires_

Shapefile: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-llopes/assets/fires_GEEex

Comment: I think something went wrong with setting your asset (fires_GEEex) to public? Just to make sure, for each fire event you want to have a time series of NDVI values up to 21 days before the fire started? Or just the mean NDVI value before the fire started based on all NDVI values up to 21 days before the event?

Comment: (I updated the sharing options of the asset, so hopefully is ok now)

Ideally, it would be the first NDVI value available (the value with closer date to the fire event) for each pixel within the polygon of the fire event. And then obtain the mean value per polygon.

Since I was strugling, in this code I was going for the mean NDVI value of the 21 days period and not first value.